# struct alignment C/C++

Tags: c++, c, memory-layout

In c/c++ (I am assuming they are the same in this regard), if I have the following:

```
struct S {
  T a;
  .
  .
  .
} s;
```

Is the following guaranteed to be true?

```
(void*)&s == (void*)&s.a;
```

Or in other words, is there any kind of guarantee that there will be no padding *before* the first member?

Comment: They aren't the same in this regard

Comment: @MooingDuck: Well, it depends on what the `...` is.  For the same struct definition, C++ will treat it the same way as C (C structures always meet the C++ *standard-layout* requirement).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In C, yes, they're the same address.  Simple, and straightforward.

---

In C++, no, they're not the same address.  Base classes can (and I would suspect, do) come before all members, and virtual member functions usually add hidden data to the struct somewhere. Even more confusing, a C++ compiler may also rearrange members at will, unless the class is a standard layout type (though I don't know that any compiler does so)

Finally, if the C++ struct is composed of *standard layout types*, contains no base classes nor virtual functions and all members have the same visibility, and possibly other limitations I forgot, *then* it falls back on the C rules, and requires the first member to be at the same address as the object itself.

§ 9.2/7

> A standard-layout class is a class that:
>   — has no non-static data members of type non-standard-layout class (or array of such types) or reference,
>   — has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1),
>   — has the same access control (Clause 11) for all non-static data members,
>   — has no non-standard-layout base classes,
>   — either has no non-static data members in the most derived class and at most one base class with non-static data members, or has no base classes with non-static data members, and
>   — has no base classes of the same type as the first non-static data member.

§ 9.2/20

> A pointer to a standard-layout struct object, suitably converted using a reinterpret_cast, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides) and vice versa. [ Note: There might therefore be unnamed padding within a standard-layout struct object, but not at its beginning, as necessary to achieve appropriate alignment. —end note ]

Comment: "standard-layout class" is also known as POD ("plain old data type"), and you can verify it using std::is_pod.

Comment: @marcin_j: No.  POD requires both *standard-layout* and *trivial construction/copy/destruction*.  A class can have non-defaulted constructors and destructors and other special members and still be *standard-layout*.

Comment: thanks for clarification, I see that it is possible to use std::is_standard_layout<T> to verify if such comparison is correct.

Comment: "Base classes can (and I would suspect, do) come before all members" -- It's undefined where bases are in layout; some compilers (none of the "mainstream" ones) do put them at the end of the class, iirc.

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch: I was aware it was IB, but I have heard that most compilers put _nonvirtual_ base classes before members, and I've heard mixed things about the placement of virtual base classes.

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch Of course it is, that's why it is a *"can"* and not a *"do"*.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, it is.

It is guaranteed there is no padding before the first struct member in C and in C++ (if it is a POD).

C quote:

> (C11, 6.7.2.1p15) "There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning."

C++ quote:

> (C++11, 9.2p20) "There might therefore be unnamed padding within a standard-layout struct object, but not at its beginning, as necessary to achieve appropriate alignment"

Comment: In C++ it is only guaranteed if it's a POD.

Comment: @n.m. added a quote for C++ and a mention for POD. Thanks

Comment: @n.m. If what is a POD? The struct `S` or the member `T`?

Comment: The comparison `&s == &s.a` is illegal, since `struct S*` and `T*` are not compatible types. But `(void*)&s == (void*)&s.a`

Comment: What if we take the address of each element of a class instance? Can they move freely after that?

Comment: @baruch: `S` (and therefore also `T`, because a `struct` is a POD only if all its members are POD).

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik If you mean move at runtime? Then no. The _compiler may_ rearrange them, but the _runtime won't_. Correctly, it _can't_ because it doesn't know where objects are located.